# Can you use more than 1 finger to modify the frequency

Tags: waves

If i have a guitar, of which the wave speed is constantly 290 m/s, the fundamental tone is 440 Hz and so, the length of the string is 1/2* (290/440) = 0.33 m.

Now, if I were to rise the frequency, I would obviously put my finger a certain distance from the antinode of the string, making the string shorter, and thus the fundamental wavelenght.

Can we actually use more fingers and then modify the frequency,for example 2 fingers, so that we create the third overtone?

Comment: But what would you be doing to the string length with the additional finger?  If one finger is used to adjust the length to get a specific wavelength, what do you plan on doing with the second finger that doesn't change the wavelength in such a way that the first finger is useless?

Comment: Well, I was thinking about using the whole length, so that you get standing waves

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VujJILOeMN4